# Issue with DC on different sites not replicating

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller, synchronization, sysvol

I have a topology with 2 sites (SiteA and SiteB).

Sites are connected thru a VPN (OpenVPN network to network), every traffic is playing well (Ping, SMB, RDP, SSH, Web etc.)

All DCs are running Windows 2012 R2.

On SiteA, I have 2 DCs running smoothly, named :

- SRV-AD1 / 192.168.100.1
- SRV-AD2 / 192.168.100.2

On SiteB, I have 2 DCs with issues, named :

- SRV-AD3 / 192.168.101.1
- SRV-AD4 / 192.168.101.2

The servers 3 and 4 are not syncing the Sysvol directory with their colleagues 1 and 2.
IP ranges and site names are set correctly under AD Sites and services, and servers are set in their correct location.

DCDiag on SRV-AD4 returns : (sorry this is a french version)

> Diagnostic du serveur d'annuaire
>
> Exécution de l'installation initiale :
>
> Tentative de recherche de serveur associé...
>
> Serveur associé : SRV-AD4
>
> - Forêt AD identifiée. 
>     Collecte des informations initiales terminée.
>
> Exécution des tests initiaux nécessaires
>
> Test du serveur : SiteB\SRV-AD4
>
> ```
>  Démarrage du test : Connectivity
>
>     ......................... Le test Connectivity
>
>      de SRV-AD4 a réussi
> ```
>
> Exécution des tests principaux
>
> Test du serveur : SiteB\SRV-AD4
>
> ```
>  Démarrage du test : Advertising
>
>     Avertissement : DsGetDcName a retourné des informations pour
>
>     \\SRV-AD1.domain.fr lors de la tentative d'accès … SRV-AD4.
>
>     Le serveur ne répond pas ou n'est pas approprié.
>
>     ......................... Le test Advertising
>
>      de SRV-AD4 a échoué
>  Démarrage du test : FrsEvent
>
>     ......................... Le test FrsEvent
>
>      de SRV-AD4 a réussi
>  Démarrage du test : DFSREvent
>
>     Erreurs ou avertissements détectés au cours des dernières 24 heures
>
>     après le partage de SYSVOL. Des problèmes liés … l'échec de la
>
>     réplication SYSVOL peuvent provoquer des problèmes de Stratégie de
>
>     groupe. 
>     ......................... Le test DFSREvent
>
>      de SRV-AD4 a réussi
>  Démarrage du test : SysVolCheck
>
>     ......................... Le test SysVolCheck
>
>      de SRV-AD4 a réussi
>  Démarrage du test : KccEvent
>
>     ......................... Le test KccEvent
>
>      de SRV-AD4 a réussi
>  Démarrage du test : KnowsOfRoleHolders
>
>     ......................... Le test KnowsOfRoleHolders
>
>      de SRV-AD4 a réussi
>  Démarrage du test : MachineAccount
>
>     ......................... Le test MachineAccount
>
>      de SRV-AD4 a réussi
>  Démarrage du test : NCSecDesc
>
>     ......................... Le test NCSecDesc
>
>      de SRV-AD4 a réussi
>  Démarrage du test : NetLogons
>
>     Impossible de se connecter au partage NETLOGON. (\\SRV-AD4\netlogon)
>
>     [SRV-AD4] Une opération net use ou LsaPolicy a échoué avec l'erreur
>
>     67, Nom de réseau introuvable..
>
>     ......................... Le test NetLogons
>
>      de SRV-AD4 a échoué
>  Démarrage du test : ObjectsReplicated
>
>     ......................... Le test ObjectsReplicated
>
>      de SRV-AD4 a réussi
>  Démarrage du test : Replications
>
>     ......................... Le test Replications
>
>      de SRV-AD4 a réussi
>  Démarrage du test : RidManager
>
>     ......................... Le test RidManager
>
>      de SRV-AD4 a réussi
>  Démarrage du test : Services
>
>     ......................... Le test Services
>
>      de SRV-AD4 a réussi
>  Démarrage du test : SystemLog
>
>     Un événement d'avertissement s'est produit. ID de l'événement :
>
>     0x0000043D
>
>        Temps généré : 01/11/2019   14:00:53
>
>        Chaîne d'événement :
>
>        Windows n'a pas pu appliquer les paramètres Group Policy Local Users and Groups. Les paramètres Group Policy Local Users and Groups possèdent peut-être leur propre fichier journal. Cliquez sur le lien "Informations".
>
>     Un événement d'avertissement s'est produit. ID de l'événement :
>
>     0x0000043D
>
>        Temps généré : 01/11/2019   14:05:55
>
>        Chaîne d'événement :
>
>        Windows n'a pas pu appliquer les paramètres Group Policy Local Users and Groups. Les paramètres Group Policy Local Users and Groups possèdent peut-être leur propre fichier journal. Cliquez sur le lien "Informations".
>
>     Un événement d'avertissement s'est produit. ID de l'événement :
>
>     0x0000043D
>
>        Temps généré : 01/11/2019   14:10:58
>
>        Chaîne d'événement :
>
>        Windows n'a pas pu appliquer les paramètres Group Policy Local Users and Groups. Les paramètres Group Policy Local Users and Groups possèdent peut-être leur propre fichier journal. Cliquez sur le lien "Informations".
>
>     Un événement d'avertissement s'est produit. ID de l'événement :
>
>     0x0000043D
>
>        Temps généré : 01/11/2019   14:16:02
>
>        Chaîne d'événement :
>
>        Windows n'a pas pu appliquer les paramètres Group Policy Local Users and Groups. Les paramètres Group Policy Local Users and Groups possèdent peut-être leur propre fichier journal. Cliquez sur le lien "Informations".
>
>     Un événement d'avertissement s'est produit. ID de l'événement :
>
>     0x0000043D
>
>        Temps généré : 01/11/2019   14:21:04
>
>        Chaîne d'événement :
>
>        Windows n'a pas pu appliquer les paramètres Group Policy Local Users and Groups. Les paramètres Group Policy Local Users and Groups possèdent peut-être leur propre fichier journal. Cliquez sur le lien "Informations".
>
>     Un événement d'avertissement s'est produit. ID de l'événement :
>
>     0x0000043D
>
>        Temps généré : 01/11/2019   14:26:07
>
>        Chaîne d'événement :
>
>        Windows n'a pas pu appliquer les paramètres Group Policy Local Users and Groups. Les paramètres Group Policy Local Users and Groups possèdent peut-être leur propre fichier journal. Cliquez sur le lien "Informations".
>
>     ......................... Le test SystemLog
>
>      de SRV-AD4 a réussi
>  Démarrage du test : VerifyReferences
>
>     ......................... Le test VerifyReferences
>
>      de SRV-AD4 a réussi
> ```
>
> Exécution de tests de partitions sur ForestDnsZones
>
> ```
>  Démarrage du test : CheckSDRefDom
>
>     ......................... Le test CheckSDRefDom
>
>      de ForestDnsZones a réussi
>  Démarrage du test : CrossRefValidation
>
>     ......................... Le test CrossRefValidation
>
>      de ForestDnsZones a réussi
> ```
>
> Exécution de tests de partitions sur DomainDnsZones
>
> ```
>  Démarrage du test : CheckSDRefDom
>
>     ......................... Le test CheckSDRefDom
>
>      de DomainDnsZones a réussi
>  Démarrage du test : CrossRefValidation
>
>     ......................... Le test CrossRefValidation
>
>      de DomainDnsZones a réussi
> ```
>
> Exécution de tests de partitions sur Schema
>
> ```
>  Démarrage du test : CheckSDRefDom
>
>     ......................... Le test CheckSDRefDom
>
>      de Schema a réussi
>  Démarrage du test : CrossRefValidation
>
>     ......................... Le test CrossRefValidation
>
>      de Schema a réussi
> ```
>
> Exécution de tests de partitions sur Configuration
>
> ```
>  Démarrage du test : CheckSDRefDom
>
>     ......................... Le test CheckSDRefDom
>
>      de Configuration a réussi
>  Démarrage du test : CrossRefValidation
>
>     ......................... Le test CrossRefValidation
>
>      de Configuration a réussi
> ```
>
> Exécution de tests de partitions sur domain
>
> ```
>  Démarrage du test : CheckSDRefDom
>
>     ......................... Le test CheckSDRefDom
>
>      de domain a réussi
>  Démarrage du test : CrossRefValidation
>
>     ......................... Le test CrossRefValidation
>
>      de domain a réussi
> ```
>
> Exécution de tests d'entreprise sur domain.fr
>
> ```
>  Démarrage du test : LocatorCheck
>
>     ......................... Le test LocatorCheck
>
>      de domain.fr a réussi
>  Démarrage du test : Intersite
>
>     ......................... Le test Intersite
>
>      de domain.fr a réussi
> ```

I suppose everything starts with the first issue :
      Démarrage du test : Advertising

```
     Avertissement : DsGetDcName a retourné des informations pour

     \\SRV-AD1.domain.fr lors de la tentative d'accès … SRV-AD4.

     Le serveur ne répond pas ou n'est pas approprié.

     ......................... Le test Advertising

      de SRV-AD4 a échoué
```

Why do I have this ? They don't have the same IP address ! Is this a known issue ? What can cause that ?

EDIT: Installed fresh new DCs on new test domain, DC1 and DC2 on Site A, DC3 on Site B. Runned smoothly until I altered the AD Schema via the Exchange setup. Since, I get the exact same errors. DC1 and DC2 are replicating well, DC3 cannot replicate anymore with its counterparts. What can be preventing spread of schema to the other site?

Comment: Hi, What OS version as I see FRS, I guess 2008R2 ?

Comment: What's the connectivity between the servers / subnets / sites? Does any other type of traffic between the servers work correctly (ping, SMB, etc)?

Comment: Edited the post to add details : all traffic running well over a VPN, every DC is pingable from any other DC. OS version is Windows 2012 R2.